# Hide Class If It Has Input Value "X"

Tags: php, css

How can I hide using CSS + PHP get parameter specific seller ( `<div class="seller">`) from the div table? Each seller have ID `<input type="hidden" value="1" name="seller_id">` if I vist the website like this:

```
website.com/?hideseller=2
```

CSS code:

```
<div class="seller-list" id="seller-list">
        <div class="head">Sellers List </div>
        <div class="title">
            <span class="lable" style="width:100px">Price</span>
            <span class="lable">Seller Information</span>
            <span class="lable">Available Products</span>
            <span class="lable"></span>
        </div>
                <div class="seller">
            <form action="checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3ByaWNlZ290by5jb20vYXBwbGUtaXBob25lLTVzLWdvbGQtMTZnYi11bmxvY2tlZC5odG1s/product/35720/form_key/2sprf498VYBVPIw0/" method="">
                <input type="hidden" value="1" name="seller_id">
                <span class="data" style="width:100px;">
                    <span class="price">$100.00</span>
                </span>
                <span class="data">
                    <a href="profile/TestUser" title="Visit Profile">
                        <img src="/media/avatar/noimage.png">
                        <div class="mp_landing_hover">
                            <span>TestUser</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </span>
                <span class="data">10</span>
                <span class="data" style="display:none;"> Qty : <input style="width:20px;" type="text" value="1" name="qty"></span>
                <span class="data">
                <input type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="addtocart" value="Add to Cart"></span>
            </form>
        </div>
                <div class="seller">
            <form action="aHR0cDovL3ByaWNlZ290by5jb20vYXBwbGUtaXBob25lLTVzLWdvbGQtMTZnYi11bmxvY2tlZC5odG1s/product/35720/form_key/2sprf498VYBVPIw0/" method="">
                <input type="hidden" value="2" name="seller_id">
                <span class="data" style="width:100px;">
                    <span class="price">$511.00</span>
                </span>
                <span class="data">
                    <a href="seller/profile/Test2" title="Visit Profile">
                        <img src="media/avatar/noimage.png">
                        <div class="mp_landing_hover">
                            <span>Test2</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </span>
                <span class="data">1111</span>
                <span class="data" style="display:none;"> Qty : <input style="width:20px;" type="text" value="1" name="qty"></span>
                <span class="data">
                <input type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="addtocart" value="Add to Cart"></span>
            </form>
        </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: `if(inputvalue is X){....}else{.....}`

Comment: What do you have so far and where are you stuck exactly? I don't see any php or relevant css.

Comment: Why is PHP relevant to this?

Comment: @jeroen well I can't even figure out how to start, I thought about something like `<?php if(isset($_GET['hideseller']) && $_GET['hideseller'] == '2'){  ?>

//css

<?php  } ?>` but I'm not sure if this a good way to do this, Also I would like it to be persistent if user visit other product

Comment: @j08691 will be javescript better fit? I choose PHP only because of the get variable is the way I want to filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide that particular `class="seller"`, first off you need to get the `$_GET['hideseller']` id, then loop it with the use of `$.each()`. Consider this example:

```
<div class="seller-list" id="seller-list">
<div class="head">Sellers List </div>
<div class="title">
    <span class="lable" style="width:100px">Price</span>
    <span class="lable">Seller Information</span>
    <span class="lable">Available Products</span>
    <span class="lable"></span>
</div>
        <div class="seller">
    <form action="checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3ByaWNlZ290by5jb20vYXBwbGUtaXBob25lLTVzLWdvbGQtMTZnYi11bmxvY2tlZC5odG1s/product/35720/form_key/2sprf498VYBVPIw0/" method="">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="seller_id">
        <span class="data" style="width:100px;">
            <span class="price">$100.00</span>
        </span>
        <span class="data">
            <a href="profile/TestUser" title="Visit Profile">
                <img src="/media/avatar/noimage.png">
                <div class="mp_landing_hover">
                    <span>TestUser</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="data">10</span>
        <span class="data" style="display:none;"> Qty : <input style="width:20px;" type="text" value="1" name="qty"></span>
        <span class="data">
        <input type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="addtocart" value="Add to Cart"></span>
    </form>
</div>
        <div class="seller">
    <form action="aHR0cDovL3ByaWNlZ290by5jb20vYXBwbGUtaXBob25lLTVzLWdvbGQtMTZnYi11bmxvY2tlZC5odG1s/product/35720/form_key/2sprf498VYBVPIw0/" method="">
        <input type="hidden" value="2" name="seller_id">
        <span class="data" style="width:100px;">
            <span class="price">$511.00</span>
        </span>
        <span class="data">
            <a href="seller/profile/Test2" title="Visit Profile">
                <img src="media/avatar/noimage.png">
                <div class="mp_landing_hover">
                    <span>Test2</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="data">1111</span>
        <span class="data" style="display:none;"> Qty : <input style="width:20px;" type="text" value="1" name="qty"></span>
        <span class="data">
        <input type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="addtocart" value="Add to Cart"></span>
    </form>
</div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var particular_id = '<?php echo isset($_GET["hideseller"]) ? $_GET["hideseller"] : "" ?>';
    if(particular_id != '') {
        $('.seller').each(function(){
            // traverse then compare
            if($(this).children().children('input[name="seller_id"]').attr('value') == particular_id) {
                $(this).hide();
            }

        });
    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted, I have added the code it does work to get `particular_id` but it will not hide, I included this in footer?

Comment: @zumbamusic i have edited the answer as i have worked on it in working state, and remember to just change your jquery path

Comment: I had `jquery-1.8.3.min.js` included thought it should work but it only worked after including `jquery.min.js` from google Thanks awesome code! If I want to make this persistent after user redirects to other pages/products I should looking into keeping the $_GET variable persistent or a better idea to have a cookie?

Comment: @zumbamusic Your welcome, yeah, alternatively, you could put it inside a cookie if its going to be persistent.

Comment: it seems now that I have a problem with the jquery if I include the one from google this script works fine but other features of the website do not, If I include the jquery-1.8.3.min.js all features works but not this script kinda lost what is this I have tried calling just 1 and not both still weird any ideas?

Comment: ah it looks like I got jquery no conflict trying to fix that code to fit it

Comment: @zumbamusic regarding that concern, i haven't tried cdn's of google's,  maybe try `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` i tried this and still works like charm

Comment: it was jquery no conflict now works :) now trying to implement some kind of system to save this after redirect visitors come to homepage after redirect to products it will not work maybe php sessions